# Prove that a manifold is not orientable

Tags: differential-geometry

I have found a proposition who says: A manifold M is not orientable if it contains a Moebius band. How can I prove this?

Comment: Interesting question: the converse implication!

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla interesting remark! Is it true?

Comment: More hypothesis required. Can you check the the exact wording?

Comment: If a Manifold isn't orientable then it contains an open subset diffeomorphic to the Moebius band.. Is this the right claim?

Comment: Open is impossible if ${\rm dim M}>2$.

Comment: a submanifold?why open is impossible?

Comment: ?!?! I misread you and understood open subset of $M$.

Comment: Definitely true for surfaces. Maybe true for embedded submanifolds (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Embedded_submanifolds). I think that the oriented atlas of $M$ restricted to the submanifold works.

Comment: Update: Klein bottle can be embedded in ${\bf R}^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

1) The mobius strip is not orientable.

2) let $f:M\rightarrow$ N  be is a diffeo. M is orientable iff N is orientable.

3) Every open subset of a orientable manifold is a orientable manifold.

Let M be the mobius strip, U subset of N and $f:U\rightarrow$ M diffeomorphism.

Suppose that N is orientable. Then by 3) we have U is a orientable manifold.

Since $f:U \rightarrow$ M is a diffeo by 2)  M is orientable. Contradition.

Answer (score 4):

If $M$ were orientable, the Moebius band will inherit the orientation of $M$.

Comment: Martin thanks for your answer. If i want to prove that the Moebius band isn't orientable, without using the vector normal, only with the definition of oriented atlas, what i might to do? I've seen there is a similar post but it don't answered completely this question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15602/why-is-the-mobius-strip-not-orientable. And maybe *Differential Forms and Applications* (do Carmo) has *another* argument that I can't remember.

Comment: I think we can´t use this argument because the mobius strip is not open. We have: If M is a orientable manifold, then every open subset of M is a orientable manifold.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is incorrect.  Euclidean space $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ contains the Mobius band but $M$ is orientable.

Comment: Is a submanifold?

Comment: The usual picture of the Mobius band in Euclidean space represents it as a submanifold. A parametrisation can be found in most elementary differential geometry textbooks.  Of course if $M$ is 2-dimensional the claim is true.

Comment: This is the exercice: I have the Moebius band M, the quotient of the square $[0,1]x\times [0,1]$ with the projection map $\pi \colon [0,1]\times [0,1]\to M$. After prove that the Moebius band isn't orientable conseider $M^°=\pi([0,1]\times (0,1)$. Show that $M^°$ and every manifold which contains an open set diffeomorphic to $M^°$ is not orientable.

Comment: So @user72694 the claim is true only in 2-dimensional manifolds? How we can generalize it for prove that a manifold isn't orientable? thanks

Comment: @user72694 the Moebius band is contained in ${\Bbb R}^3$ like ${\Bbb R}^2$ in ${\Bbb R}^3$? There are several definitions of submanifolds with adjectives. In any case, you are right, the simple condition of subset isn't enough. More is required.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla however, what is the right claim? what hyp. needs?

Comment: @user72694, please, can you check if my comment about embedded submanifolds makes sense?